# Admob: insert my own, alternative ads once in a while

Tags: admob

Is it possible to insert ads to other sites like it is with Adsense to enter alternative URLs for "empty slots"? I've digged through the Admob settings and the methods for AdView and AdMobAdapterExtras but found nothing that looked like it. If there indeed isn't anything like that, did anyone implement a way to achieve displaying alternate ads in a certain frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you mean but in AdMob you can show House Ads, these are your own Ads, you can set the percentage of impressions that will show house Ads instead of real Ads, you create these Ads in the AdMob console, no code has to change.

Comment: thanks! Now I still have to find this option (I couldn't find it before) but knowing it HAS to be there somewhere already helps. :)